# Google Sites defined dropdown items close immedately when used on Android device

Tags: mobile, navigation, google-sites

I used standard Google Sites definitions for my horizontal navigation bar. The result works as expected on a normal browser on my PC.

[image]

The dropdown items "Start the App" and "Serial number identification" show up and I can tick them so that the relevant page is opened.

However when I use Chrome on Android (5.1.1) on a Nexus and go to the same page, the effect is that the navigation bar appears but when I touch "Manual", the sub-items show up for half a second and then disappear.

I have tried all variations in respect to layout type and format but the result is always identical.

How can this be resolved?